# RaycastHit could not be found error *Unity*

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm following this YouTube tutorial : https://youtu.be/HhFoFWjR2WA

And I wrote the code as it is and when I saved and go to Unity it said this error: **The type or namespace name 'RayCastHit' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Here's the copy of code.....

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerCasting : MonoBehaviour {

    public static float DistanceFromTarget;
    public float ToTarget;


    void Update () {
        RaycastHit Hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward), out Hit)) {
            ToTarget = Hit.distance;
            DistanceFromTarget = ToTarget;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: check the unity version?

Comment: did you typo the error message? because the error says 'RayCastHit' not 'RaycastHit'

Comment: @viveknuna  My unity version is 2018.4.26 and 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you misspelled RaycastHit in your code, if untiy is setup correctly you can just double click the error message and it should open the code where Unity found the syntax error. Otherwise the error message should also tell you the script and row where the error happens

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't know why when I restarted unity my script works fine . I think it was just a bug or something...